# Meaning of arrows in 3D representation of proteins

Tags: biochemistry, 3d-structure

[image: CD4 structure]

Below is a three-dimensional representation of the protein, CD4. I would like to know what the arrows and the thin wires between them mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flat arrows are a cartoon representation of β-strands (one type of regular hydrogen-bonded secondary structure). The direction of the arrow is the direction of the amino acid sequence (arrow head pointing towards the *C*-terminus).

The thin wires are regions with no regular structure.

There are also two small green spiral ribbons in the foreground left and right, which represent α-helices (the other main regular secondary structure).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. It is really hard to find that information since there is no keywords to google..

Comment: You're welcome. I was looking for something else and it just caught my eye.

Comment: There *are* two small helices, but the structure is generally a beta-sandwich.

Comment: @gilleain Thanks. I hadn't noticed. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @m1clee The keywords you need for Google are "[ribbon diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_diagram)" or "Richardson diagram".